# Invalid literal for int

Tags: python, int

I have a function:

```
import urllib2
import json
id = u'asadasd58'
if not id.isdigit:
    url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key='+SteamKey+'&vanityurl='+id
    file = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    file = json.loads(file, 'utf-8')
    if file['response']['success'] == 1:
        print file['response']['steamid']
    else:
        print 0
else:
    print int(id)
```

It's supposed to work like so: if 64 bit SteamID (or just a number) is supplied, it's simply printed. If it is not just a number, we try to get if it is a vanity url, and resolve real 64 bit id, if we fail to resolve (file['response']['success'] == 42) then we return 0. But when you supply id above, it tries to int it, even though it isn't digit. Why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 13, in <module> print int(id) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asadasd58'
```

Comment: Try not to use `id` as a variable name, it's a python method which, if you overwrite it, could throw some weird errors further down the line if you tried to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know your full traceback, but...

```
id = u'asadasd58'
if not id.isdigit():  # call this function! with real parentheses!
    ...
else:
    print int(id)     # this will fail!
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print int(id)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asadasd58'

Comment: Edit your question and put it there. But yeah, it's failing because you're not calling `isdigit`. You're just checking if the function itself "is not"

Comment: It happens to all of us :)